# Fetch the pdf file from every 2nd row of 2nd column of html table in python through selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to web scraping. I need to fetch the pdf file from every 2nd row of 2nd column of below HTML table code:

```
<table class="tablebg" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" align="left">Nov 09, 2017</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word;width:450;">
                        <a class="link2" href="FS_Notification.aspx?Id=11162&amp;fn=5&amp;Mode=0">Risk Management and Inter-Bank Dealings – Simplified Hedging Facility</a>
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap="" colspan="3">
                        <a target="_blank" href="http://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/notification/PDFs/APD118ED4C6E75FAC43A0BA5A738C21F8A8A7.PDF"><img src="../Images/pdf.gif" border="0" align="bsmiddle"></a>
                        97 kb
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I have tried below code but its not picking up the 2nd column of 2nd row:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
browser = driver.get("https://rbi.org.in/")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FEMA"]/a""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FEMANotifications"]""").click()
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr")

for rows in result:
    second_row = result.__getitem__(2)
    second_col = second_row.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("http://")
    print(second_col)
```

Please suggest any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print every 2nd row of 2nd column of html table you can use the following line of code :

```
print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='tablebg']//tr//td/a[contains(@href,'http://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/notification/PDFs')]").get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: ..or simply `//table[@class="tablebg"]//a[img]`

Comment: I think OP needed to keep the constraint `2nd row of 2nd column` so kept `//tr//td`. Makes sense ?  Sir @Andersson

Comment: As only second `td` of second `tr` has link with `img` (the PDF icon), `//tr//td` might be ignored

Comment: @Andersson Pretty much logical.

Comment: @DebanjanB: It works! Thanks a lot for you help. However, it will only one pdf link and I need for every row wherever PDF link is present. With the help of your code, I have used below code and it got me what I needed:  
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='tablebg']//tr//td/a[contains(@href,'http://')]")
for row in rows:
    pdf = row.get_attribute('href')
    print(pdf)